# Updating multiple lines in SQL specifies wrong type for null value

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hello i'm trying to update multiple lines in my table and I used this sql but although suggestion is integer nullable but i throws error `column suggestion is of type integer but expression is of type text`

SQL:

```
 UPDATE shipment_item AS ass
 SET units_per_box = av.units_per_box,
     boxes = av.boxes,
     box_per_pallet = av.box_per_pallet,
     suggestion = av.suggestion
     FROM (VALUES  (20091,36,2,44,null)  ) AS av
 (id,units_per_box,boxes,
  box_per_pallet,suggestion)
```

Comment: Try `null::int`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that actually worked. Can you add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any unidentifiable constant like NULL or a string literal in a `VALUES` statement will be coerced to type `text` in recent PostgreSQL versions:

```
SELECT pg_typeof(c3)
FROM (VALUES (1, 1.2, NULL)) AS a(c1,c2,c3);

 pg_typeof 
═══════════
 text
(1 row)
```

So you should apply an explicit type cast: `NULL::integer`.